# Playframework plugins and generics

Tags: scala, generics, playframework, scala-2.10

I would like to implement a situation like this: abstract class with a generic parameter and a concrete plugin that implements this class.

for example:

```
abstract class BasePlugin[T] extends Plugin {
  def d: T
}

class MyPlugin(app: Application) extends BasePlugin[String] {
  val d = "test" 
}
```

My desire is to achieve the following:

```
val plugin = app.plugin[BasePlugin[String]]
//Ok, plugin = Some(MyPlugin)

val plugin = app.plugin[BasePlugin[Int]]
//KO, plugin = None
```

Of course this does not happen, because myPlugin is found using any type as a parameter (type erasure?).
In any case it would be very effective for me to find a technique to obtain the above. Any idea?

Comment: Scala has something called a ClassTag, it makes it possible to retain type information even when the app has compiled. It was called Manifest before scala 2.10. Maybe you could use them to get around the problem?!

Answer (score 1):

The play plugin api uses Class.isAssignableFrom when it looks for plugins which is part of Java so it will not help that Scala has got ClassTag/TypeTags.

Maybe you could create your own sub-plugin format, something like:

```
trait SubPlugin[T] {
  def doSomething(t: T) {}
}

trait MetaPlugin {

  private val subPlugins: Seq[(Class[_], SubPlugin[_])] = ???

  def subPlugin[T](implicit classTag: ClassTag[T]): Option[SubPlugin[T]] = {
    subPlugins.collectFirst {
      case (c, p) if c.isAssignableFrom(classTag.runtimeClass) => p.asInstanceOf[SubPlugin[T]]
    }
  }
}

object MetaPlugin {

  def apply[T](implicit app: play.api.Application, classTag: ClassTag[T]): Option[SubPlugin[T]] =
    app.plugin[MetaPlugin].flatMap(_.subPlugin[T])

}


object AndThenSomeWhere {
  import play.api.Play.current
  MetaPlugin[String].map(_.doSomething("a string"))
}
```